# 500 Internal Server Error on signing page in VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am getting 500 internal server error on signing page in Visual Studio Team Services site. I am trying to login VSTS to other browsers but not yet working.

Please look at the issue and give me your suggestion to solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Have you got the 500 error now? It should be the VSTS service outage event as Sheethal said.

Comment: yes. now it is working fine. thank you for updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks there is currently a service outage, which is the likely cause of what you're seeing. Check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=15625 and Keep an eye on that link for the resolution. Hopefully, it will be up again shortly.